# Can we save attachment in activity using apex

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage, activities

I'm using an apex single email message to send an email with an attachment. Everything is working fine. But in the activity history, I can only see email body details but attachment not saved in activity.

I have checked "Always save email attachments" under "My Email to Salesforce".
[image]

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstsendmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Id template_id =  [SELECT id, name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developername ='Send_Invoice_PDF'].Id;
List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
toAddresses.add('test@test.com');  // e.g email address                        
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setWhatId(inv); // Custom object(Invoice) id
mail.setTargetObjectId(cont.Id); // Activity save in contact
mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
mail.setTemplateId(template_id);
List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>(); 
Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
efa.setFileName(cv.Title);
efa.setBody(cv.VersionData); // File version data(blob)
fileAttachments.add(efa);
mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
lstsendmails.add(mail);

List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> sendEmailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(lstsendmails,false);
```

Please advise on this

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce stores files inside **ContentVersion** and its controllability is handled parent record of **ContentDocumentLink**.

To attach the file with a record you have to create a ContentDocumentLink record. ContentDocumentLink's LinkedEntityId field stores the ID of the record to which you want to link the attachment.

So you can not have multiple parents of the same file.

To resolve this, you must create a new ContentVersion and a new  ContentDocumentLink record.

Refer to the below code -

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstsendmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Id template_id =  [SELECT id, name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developername ='SupportSelfServiceResetPassword'].Id;
List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
toAddresses.add('dummy@gmail.com');  // e.g email address                        
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
//mail.setWhatId('0035j000016vu84AAA'); // Custom object(Invoice) id
mail.setTargetObjectId('0035j000016vu84AAA'); // Activity save in contact
mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
mail.setTemplateId(template_id);
//List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>(); 
Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
ContentVersion cv = [SELECT id,title,VersionData,FileType FROM contentversion where id='0685j00000MDaxaAAD'];
ContentVersion c1 = new ContentVersion();
c1.Title = cv.title;
c1.VersionData = cv.VersionData;
c1.PathOnClient = '/' + cv.title;
insert c1;
ContentVersion c2 = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId,versiondata
                     FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :c1.Id LIMIT 1];
efa.setFileName(c2.Title);
efa.setBody(c2.VersionData); // File version data(blob)
mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
lstsendmails.add(mail);

List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> sendEmailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(lstsendmails,false);
system.debug(sendEmailResults[0]);
ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cl.ContentDocumentId = c2.ContentDocumentId;
cl.LinkedEntityId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage ORDER BY CreatedDate desc LIMIT 1].Id;
cl.ShareType = 'V';
cl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert cl;
```

I'm querying the **EmailMessage** as per the screenshot you want to attach file here.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
mail.setEntityAttachments(new List<Id>(/*contentVersionIds*/))
```

instead of:

```
mail.setFileAttachments()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. Please check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404493/attachments-sent-from-apex-are-not-stored-in-the-emailmessage-record-or-the-pare