# Attachments sent from Apex are not stored in the EmailMessage record or the parent Case record

Tags: email, attachment, singleemailmessage

I'm using

```
`<lightning-file-upload
                  label="Attach files"
                  name="fileUploader"
                  accept={acceptedFormats}
                  record-id={recordId}
                  onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                  multiple>
              </lightning-file-upload>`
```

to upload attachments to an email sent in LWC from a Case record. The attachment is working fine and the email is being sent with the attachments. However, the attachments are not present anywhere in the Case record. I checked the EmailMessage record, Activity History and even the Attachments related list under Case. My Apex code -

```
@AuraEnabled Public static string sendEmail(String emailDetailStr,
                                              String emailBody,
                                              String recordId) {
    List<String> contentVersionIds = new List<String>();
    EmailWrapper emailDetails =
        (EmailWrapper)JSON.deserialize(emailDetailStr, EmailWrapper.class);

    for (ContentDocument document :
         [SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id
             IN:emailDetails.files]) {
      contentVersionIds.add(document.LatestPublishedVersionId);
    }
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    email.setWhatId(recordId); //Case record Id
    email.setSubject(emailDetails.subject);
    email.setToAddresses(emailDetails.toAddress.split(';'));
    email.setEntityAttachments(contentVersionIds);
    email.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
    if (emailDetails.fromAddress != UserInfo.getUserEmail()) {
      OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea =
          [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address
              =:emailDetails.fromAddress];
      if (owea.size() > 0) {
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
      }
    }
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emailList =
        new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email};
    Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
    return 'success';
  }
```

Comment: Follow the answer I have shared here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313256/can-we-save-attachment-in-activity-using-apex